# Why is != early in the if statement not the same as if it were on the end?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I can't figure out what the difference is between the two if conditions. It seems the same to me.

Adding parentheses so that it is `((field[i][j] != -1)` does not change anything either.

```
if (field[i][j] != -1 && i>=0 && i< numRows && j >= 0 && j < numCols){} 
//wrong version 
is NOT the same as 
if (0 <= i && i < numRows && 0 <= j && j < numCols && field[i][j] != -1){}
//right version
```

Comment: what's your problem exactly? You say wrong but wrong why?

Comment: What's the problem with the "wrong" version? How does it behave differently? You're getting an exception, perhaps?

Comment: The first one might throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when `i` or `j` is less then 0

Comment: Conditions are evaluated left to right. If any condition fails then `&&` short-circuits. Therefor, the two if(s) are not equivalent.

Comment: `&&` is a short circuiting operation, so if `i` or `j` are out of bounds, in the second version `field[i][j]` is never reaches, so no exception is thrown

Answer (score 9):

```
if (field[i][j] != -1 && i>=0 && i< numRows && j >= 0 && j < numCols){} //wrong version
```

is NOT the same as

```
if (0 <= i && i < numRows && 0 <= j && j < numCols && field[i][j] != -1){} //right version
```

Without seeing additional code, it's hard to say.  `&&` short circuits ([Short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)) mean the code will stop running the instant something is `false`.  In the right version, I am guessing one of the boolean checks is false before `field[i][j] != -1` is ultimately reached. Likely, there is some sort of bounds exception happening there.

Answer (score 3):

`&&` is lazy operator.

If the left side is evaluated as `false`, then there is no need to evaluate the right side because the result of the overall operation is already known.

It may lead to a difference between `a && b` and `b && a`.

Lets look at `a && b`. In this case `b` suffers a side effect (like throwing an exception as in your code). If `a` is evaluated to `false`, then `b` will not be evaluated at all.